# What is the format of joomla password?

Tags: joomla

hi do you know what is the format of password generated by joomla?

i think this is not normal MD5

this is the password:

> $2y$10$lxKOLcaQxC./q/iO5GkGfuAvUNdpaji1Fi0RsRWmbre.6uFSP7U1m

Answer (score 1):

`bcrypt, Blowfish(OpenBSD)`

According to http://www.onlinehashcrack.com/hash-identification.php

Comment: thank you i try it with this method password_hash($pass,PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
 this method generate different hash for same password how bcrypt identify the generated hash is to stored hash in db?

Comment: @Edalat - Joomla 3.x uses Bcrypt which is a one-way hashing algorithm. It won't be the same each time you try to hash a string. Please do some research on how to match hashes in Joomla

Comment: @Lodder i searched about how to match hashes in joomla and find this method password_verify($password, $hashedPassword); this method verify user entered pass with hash of password stored in database and return true if $password and  $hashedPassword is match togheter